# Git show diff between one file on 2 branches to make them equal

Tags: git, diff, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, meld

I have the same file on development_branch and on master branch. The correct version of the file is on development_branch and the version on master branch is very outdated.

I know for sure that the version on development_branch is 100% accurate and I could simply replace the file on master branch to be 1:1 equal, but I want to keep the commit history, so is there any way I could get the commits from development_branch that are not on master branch to easily make it equal?

There were some conflicts during merging and some of them might have been resolved incorrectly, in an incorrect order, there were many modifications etc. I want to get the exact file I have on the development_branch as an output.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Merge develop into master, assuming you want all content from develop, pause the commit and checkout develop version of file

```
git merge  --no-commit develop
git checkout develop -- PATH_TO_FILE
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know for sure that the version on development_branch is 100% accurate and I could simply replace the file on master branch to be 1:1 equal, but I want to keep the commit history ...

There is only one kind of history in a Git repository, and that history is the set of commits in the repository.

Adding new commits to the repository does not change the existing commits in the repository.  It literally *cannot* change them.

Hence all you need to do in this case is extract the desired contents from the commit that has them, write them to your index (which is where Git builds the *next* commit to make), and make a new commit.  To do that:

```
# git checkout master  # if needed - but you're already there
git checkout development_branch -- path/to/file
```

and you should now be ready to `git commit` the updated file (use `git status`, `git diff --cached`, etc., to make sure).

(In Git 2.23 or later, you can use `git restore` instead of `git checkout`-for-a-single-file.  The command line you end up typing in is longer, but the operation is clearer: the goal is to extract the given file from the given commit, writing it to both index and work-tree.)